# How much electricity do voltage stabilizers consume?

Tags: power, voltage-regulator

I have recently installed a Voltage Stabilizer of 1000VA. When I got previous month's electricity bill, I was thundered. The bill was 3 times more than what I get usually.

I have not installed any new electrical appliance or device after I have installed the Stabilizer and I am only using the Stabilizer for my Router, PC, Laptop and TV.

I would like to know if I keep the Stabilizer running for 24/7 how much power it can consume ?

P.S. I use the TV as a Laptop's 2nd monitor and not used more than 2 hours a day. The router is on 24/7 and the laptop runs about 14-16 hrs/day.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us a model number? This can depend quite a bit on how exact unit works. Some will only work when input voltage doesn't satisfy given conditions while others some will work all the time. There are also differences in efficiency, some units are more efficient, as in ratio between input and output power is lower, some units are less efficient. This also then depends on the trade-off between efficiency and voltage conditioning. Units which give cleanest output will in general be less efficient. Of course, this is all hand-waving without any concrete information.

Comment: Why do you think you need a voltage stabilizer, anyway?  All of the devices you mention will not benefit from a voltage stabilizer as they should all have switching power supplies with wide input voltage ranges.  You only really need a stabilizer when you have devices with narrow input voltage ranges, such as audio equipment and old test equipment.

Comment: Don't speculate, measure.

Comment: @AndrejaKo its a chinese brand Sako. Model: SVR-1000VA

Comment: @alex.forencich If it is safe without using one I won't. Thanks for the info.

Comment: If you're looking for protection from undervoltage and overvoltage, get a surge protector and/or a UPS.  A voltage stabilizer really isn't going to help you in that regard.

Comment: _"The bill was 3 times more than what I get usually."_ - How many kWh would you expect for a normal month, and how many were on this bill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a typical servo voltage stabilizer specification sheet:

[image]

Efficiency will be given at **full rated load**, so if you have a 1kVA stabilizer it will waste about 40W. At less than full load, the losses and the **efficiency will be less** because there are two components to the losses- fixed and variable. The fixed loss for a good 1kVA variac (eg. Staco) might be 5-10W, and 98% at full load. So if we assume 10-20W fixed vampire loss for this Chinese one (no load), your no-load consumption would be around 7-15kWh/month.

Since electricity costs around 10 cents US per kWh in many places where voltage stabilizers would be useful, that's about $1/month.

If the stabilizer is boosting voltage that was otherwise low, or vice versa, to loads that are constant resistance (more or less) then the consumption will change because of that, but not by 3:1. So, your consumption should not be increased by much more than (say) 20% + 15kWh/month.

Back in the old days, when people went around reading old-fashioned non-smart mechanical energy meters, there was sometimes a correction because the power company would estimate monthly power consumption based on previous usage patterns, and if the real situation was different there might be a relatively large correction when the estimates were reconciled with reality. Perhaps that is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tradeegypt.com/sako-regulator/?ID=73567&CatalogID=18676&link=products&catname=Electronics+%26+Electrical&sub2id=280&catid=9

claims effifiency 95% (which is about what I would expect for an autotransformer type AVR)  I would look elsewhere for your increase in consumption.

Comment: Yes, one of those.

Answer (score 0):

I plugged my Triplite 1700w AVR into the Kill-a-Watt and it read 14w with no loads attached. So I guessing that about 14w is the overhead if the reading was accurate.

But since it's a big autotransformer (inductive) with buck and boost capability that's not too bad. Just is it to be trusted as close or could it be way way off? Efficiency is also about 95% in the specs. But if I were to figure it based on 1700 then it's more like 80w overhead at full rating? And I'm guessing at low or no load it's closer to 85% efficient if we are consuming 14w.